# Unable to sent email using Amazon SES

Tags: amazon-ses

I have configured my WHM for the exim "Mail Server" with Amazon SES details. All my emails route with the local mail server generated in cPanel through SES after domain verification. This time email is generated under the remote mail server. When I'm trying to send the email from Remote Routing it gives me an error. I have checked everything with the AWS support team and all is working fine with local mail configuration inside cPanel because the email is generated with cPanel but if the email is not generated it is taking server address as a sender address and in this case email is rejecting.

However emails through hostname is not sending to the destination

Please suggest what should I do in this case?

SES is alreay configured in exim setting. Emails generated inside cpanel is fine but for remote mails are not working.